Has Google allowed Figma to bypass the 403 Disallowed Useragent error for in-app webview Google logins?
I’ve encountered the “403 Disallowed Useragent” error when attempting Google logins in many in-app webviews (e.g., in messenger apps or embedded browsers), which Google restricts for security reasons. However, Figma seems to be an exception, allowing Google login to work flawlessly even in these restricted environments.
I suspect Google might have made an exception for Figma, allowing them to bypass this restriction. Does anyone know if Figma has a special arrangement with Google or if there’s a technical reason why they are allowed to bypass this restriction? Any insights into how this is achieved would be helpful!
I’ve tried to replicate the behavior by modifying different parameters like client_id, redirect_uri, and referrer (which works in normal web env) in the login request to simulate Figma’s process. However, I still encounter the “403 Disallowed Useragent” error, no matter what changes I make.
Is there any way to make the google login flow work like figma does?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
